# error with dimensions in Simulink

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, matlab, simulation

I am trying to simulate a **cartesian regulator** for a unicycle with Simulink and I am having some problems.

My simulink model is the following:

[image]

and when I run it I get the following error message:

[image]

so it seems I am doing something wrong with the dimensions.

I have added also some **ToWorkspace** blocks since I want to use the results to do some plots.

I have not very good at using Simulink, so I am having a lot of problem and **I don't know how to solve the error message I get.**

Cab somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the output of the regulator into to seperate signals.

```
function [v_out, omega_out] = C_REG(q)
...
v_out = v;
omega_out = omega;
```

You are probably compounding the signals in a different way then Simulink is trying to demux it. You can use a Mux block if you really want just one signal path.

There is also a change that simply changing the last line to a row vector instead of a column vector could also help

```
inputs=[v,omega];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried the solutions that you have suggested me, but I still get the same error.

Comment: In the case when you have 2 output signals from your regulator block, and use a mux to compound these signals, at least the error message has to change.

Comment: Alternatively you can try to remake the u(1)*sin(u2) part with multiplier blocks. Maybe the reference to the elements of the input signals causes the problems....